# How to I replace the default logo in transactional emails?

Tags: magento

I don't want to create templates for all transactional emails but I would like to replace the default Magento logo used for emails.

I know that I can go into the base directory and replace it, but if I upgrade the system it will wipe it out. Does anyone know the proper way to change it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a new theme and place it there. This isn't as difficult as it sounds because of the way themes fall back onto defaults in Magento. If Magento can't find something in your theme, it will fall back onto the base theme by looking in the `default` folder.

For example, in a store that I maintain, I uploaded my own version of the e-mail logo image in

`/skin/frontend/{package}/{my-theme-name}/images/logo_email.gif`

and in the Administration panel, I went to System > Configuration > Design > Themes and set `Default` to `{my-theme-name}`.

Why does this work?

In the e-mail templates, Magento specifies the `src` of the logo image as `{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}`. This is Magento template gibberish for "find the `images/logo_email.gif` in the `frontend` area of the current theme." So Magento looks in for `/frontend/{package}/{my-theme-name}/images/logo_email.gif`, finds it, and uses that path when dishing out the HTML.

If you delete your image, it doesn't break! Instead, although Magento would still first search in your theme directory as described above, it would discover that it doesn't exist and fall back onto the one in `/frontend/{package}/default/images/logo_email.gif`.

Good luck, and hope this helps!

Comment: Magento 1.7.0.2 the logo is specified as `{{var logo_url}}` - looking for a solution for this case. Maybe I'll do a search and replace...

Answer (score 34):

Another correct way to do that is to go in BackEnd to System>>Configuration>>Design>>Transactional Emails>>Logo Image 
and easily pick your logo image from there.
GL.

Comment: I suppose this only works if you use the proper variable for this in the template. It doesn't work with the template I use, although I would prefer this method because it's so much better than copying a template just for a logo.

Comment: ALWAYS check what your current store is before changing settings ha

Answer (score 5):

The best answer for handling logos in transactional emails is a combination of the previous answers.

Select the logo for your transactional emails by going here: **System -> Configuration -> Design -> Transactional Emails -> Logo Image**

Then, in your transactional emails ensure that they reference: `{{var logo_url}}` for the url of the logo.

I upgraded from an older version of Magento and it had `{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}` for the logo url. This older method referenced the logo_email.gif stuck in the default image folder.

Comment: While others mentioned parts of the information written in your answer (upload in the admin, or use {{var ...}}), your answer provides the entire process. This is the best answer for anyone using Magento 1.7+.

Answer (score 4):

For magento 1.9, if you want to change transactional mails' logo for all templates follow this:

System -> Configuration -> Design -> Transactional Emails -> Logo Image

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 1.7.0.2 < use `{{var logo_url}}` instead of `{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the email client will keep a cached version of the image.
I was viewing the correct image in the browser by copying the url from the email source code, but still Mail on Mac Os was displaying the demo store logo...