# Change logo in transactional email

Tags: magento

I have a transactional email with the following code:

```
<a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
```

and a logo in /public_html/skin/frontend/fortis/default/images
called logo.png
What I should put in store url="" and in {{var logo_url}} to show my logo in the transactional email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change this globally, go to:

> System > Configuration > General > Design > Transactional Emails

and upload it there. I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

You Should have an image in your folder called `logo_email.gif` same as `logo_print.gif` for the "Print View" pages.

So:

"/public_html/skin/frontend/fortis/default/images/logo_email.gif"

Answer (score 4):

If you have to use your logo.png file you need to use something like this

```
src="{{skin url="images/logo.png" _area='frontend' _package="fortis" _theme="default"}}"
```

But the better way would to be to convert your email logo, as suggested by SteveyO, to email_logo.gif and put it into /public_html/skin/frontend/fortis/default/images/logo_email.gif so you don't need to edit every transactional email and make sure that everything is set up in system->configuration->general->design

More info can be found here [How to I replace the default logo in transactional emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985376/how-to-i-replace-the-default-logo-in-transactional-emails)

Answer (score 2):

You should change that in the Magento backend (configuration > design > transactional e-mails).

Answer (score 2):

For this, In the skin hierarchy of your theme under this **skin/frotend/default/YOUR_THEME/images** structure you should have your logo file naming it as "logo_email.gif". Just replace this with your new logo file (keeping the same name).

This won't require any further updations, clear the cache and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

To change this globally, go to:

System>Configuration>General>Design>Transactional Emails and upload it there. I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1